# Caffe Loss Doesn't Decrease

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I am a new user to caffe and I've basically made small modifications to the [FCN](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org) model to train on my own data. I've noticed that after 680 iterations the loss has not changed. I thought maybe it was because I was applying a scale of 1/255 on the pixels, but I've removed that and there was no change.

My data is in LMDB (1 LMDB for training images, 1 LMDB for training labels, 1 for validation and 1 for validation labels) and the labels are 0 and 1 stored as uint8.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
I0830 23:05:45.645638 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 0 (0 iter/s, 74.062s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0830 23:05:45.647449 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0830 23:05:45.647469 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 0, lr = 1e-14
I0830 23:28:42.183948 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 20 (0.0145293 iter/s, 1376.53s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0830 23:28:42.185940 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0830 23:28:42.185962 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 20, lr = 1e-14
I0830 23:51:43.803419 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 40 (0.0144758 iter/s, 1381.62s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0830 23:51:43.817291 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0830 23:51:43.817371 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 40, lr = 1e-14
I0831 00:17:23.955076 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 60 (0.0129858 iter/s, 1540.14s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 00:17:23.957161 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 00:17:23.957203 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 60, lr = 1e-14
I0831 00:40:41.079898 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 80 (0.0143152 iter/s, 1397.12s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 00:40:41.082603 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 00:40:41.082649 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 80, lr = 1e-14
I0831 01:03:53.159317 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 100 (0.014367 iter/s, 1392.08s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 01:03:53.161844 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 01:03:53.161903 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 100, lr = 1e-14
I0831 01:27:03.867575 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 120 (0.0143812 iter/s, 1390.71s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 01:27:03.869439 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 01:27:03.869469 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 120, lr = 1e-14
I0831 01:50:10.512094 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 140 (0.0144233 iter/s, 1386.64s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 01:50:10.514268 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 01:50:10.514302 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 140, lr = 1e-14
I0831 02:09:50.607455 26275840 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0831 02:09:50.672649 25739264 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0831 02:13:16.209158 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 160 (0.0144332 iter/s, 1385.69s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 02:13:16.211565 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 02:13:16.211609 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 160, lr = 1e-14
I0831 02:36:30.536650 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 180 (0.0143439 iter/s, 1394.32s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 02:36:30.538833 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 02:36:30.539871 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 180, lr = 1e-14
I0831 02:59:38.813151 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 200 (0.0144064 iter/s, 1388.27s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 02:59:38.814018 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 02:59:38.814097 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 200, lr = 1e-14
I0831 03:22:46.534659 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 220 (0.0144121 iter/s, 1387.72s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 03:22:46.536751 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 03:22:46.536808 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 220, lr = 1e-14
I0831 03:46:38.997651 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 240 (0.013962 iter/s, 1432.46s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 03:46:39.001502 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 03:46:39.001591 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 240, lr = 1e-14
I0831 04:09:49.981889 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 260 (0.0143784 iter/s, 1390.98s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 04:09:49.983256 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 04:09:49.983301 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 260, lr = 1e-14
I0831 04:32:59.845221 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 280 (0.0143899 iter/s, 1389.86s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 04:32:59.847712 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 04:32:59.847936 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 280, lr = 1e-14
I0831 04:56:07.752025 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 300 (0.0144102 iter/s, 1387.9s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 04:56:07.754050 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 04:56:07.754091 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 300, lr = 1e-14
I0831 05:16:57.383947 26275840 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0831 05:16:57.468634 25739264 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0831 05:19:16.101671 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 320 (0.0144056 iter/s, 1388.35s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 05:19:16.102998 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 05:19:16.103953 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 320, lr = 1e-14
I0831 05:42:22.554265 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 340 (0.0144253 iter/s, 1386.45s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 05:42:22.557201 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 05:42:22.558081 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 340, lr = 1e-14
I0831 06:05:33.816596 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 360 (0.0143755 iter/s, 1391.26s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 06:05:33.819310 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 06:05:33.819358 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 360, lr = 1e-14
I0831 06:28:38.358750 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 380 (0.0144452 iter/s, 1384.54s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 06:28:38.362834 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 06:28:38.363451 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 380, lr = 1e-14
I0831 06:51:48.489392 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 400 (0.0143872 iter/s, 1390.13s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 06:51:48.490061 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 06:51:48.491013 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 400, lr = 1e-14
I0831 07:15:00.156152 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 420 (0.0143713 iter/s, 1391.67s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 07:15:00.159214 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 07:15:00.159261 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 420, lr = 1e-14
I0831 07:38:09.862089 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 440 (0.0143916 iter/s, 1389.7s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 07:38:09.865105 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 07:38:09.865152 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 440, lr = 1e-14
I0831 08:01:15.438222 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 460 (0.0144345 iter/s, 1385.57s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 08:01:15.439589 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 08:01:15.440675 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 460, lr = 1e-14
I0831 08:24:24.188830 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 480 (0.0144015 iter/s, 1388.75s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 08:24:24.191907 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 08:24:24.191951 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 480, lr = 1e-14
I0831 08:24:24.514991 26275840 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0831 08:24:24.524113 25739264 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0831 08:47:29.558264 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 500 (0.0144366 iter/s, 1385.37s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 08:47:29.562070 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 08:47:29.562104 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 500, lr = 1e-14
I0831 09:10:43.430681 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 520 (0.0143486 iter/s, 1393.87s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 09:10:43.432601 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 09:10:43.433498 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 520, lr = 1e-14
I0831 09:33:53.022397 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 540 (0.0143927 iter/s, 1389.59s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 09:33:53.024354 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 09:33:53.024405 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 540, lr = 1e-14
I0831 09:56:59.140298 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 560 (0.0144288 iter/s, 1386.11s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 09:56:59.142597 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 09:56:59.142642 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 560, lr = 1e-14
I0831 10:20:10.334044 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 580 (0.0143762 iter/s, 1391.19s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 10:20:10.336256 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 10:20:10.336287 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 580, lr = 1e-14
I0831 10:43:15.363580 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 600 (0.0144402 iter/s, 1385.03s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 10:43:15.365350 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 10:43:15.365380 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 600, lr = 1e-14
I0831 11:06:26.864280 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 620 (0.014373 iter/s, 1391.5s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 11:06:26.867431 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 11:06:26.867480 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 620, lr = 1e-14
I0831 11:29:37.275745 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 640 (0.0143843 iter/s, 1390.41s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 11:29:37.277166 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 11:29:37.277206 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 640, lr = 1e-14
I0831 11:30:47.900959 26275840 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0831 11:30:47.934394 25739264 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0831 11:53:00.394335 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 660 (0.014254 iter/s, 1403.11s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 11:53:00.399102 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 11:53:00.399185 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 660, lr = 1e-14
I0831 12:16:24.352802 2989601728 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 680 (0.0142455 iter/s, 1403.95s/20 iters), loss = 190732
I0831 12:16:24.355890 2989601728 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 190732 (* 1 = 190732 loss)
I0831 12:16:24.356781 2989601728 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 680, lr = 1e-14
```

This is my the definition of the network for the training phase:

```
name: "face-detect"
state {
  phase: TRAIN
  level: 0
  stage: ""
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mean_value: 104.006989
    mean_value: 116.66877
    mean_value: 122.678917
  }
  data_param {
    source: "data/fddb-face-database/train_img_lmdb"
    scale: 0.00390625
    batch_size: 16
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "label"
  type: "Data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  data_param {
    source: "data/fddb-face-database/train_lab_lmdb"
    batch_size: 16
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod1_conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "mod1_conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod1_relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "mod1_conv1"
  top: "mod1_conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "mod1_conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "mod1_conv1"
  top: "mod1_conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod1_relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "mod1_conv2"
  top: "mod1_conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "mod1_pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "mod1_conv2"
  top: "mod1_pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod2_conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "mod1_pool1"
  top: "mod2_conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod2_relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "mod2_conv1"
  top: "mod2_conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "mod2_conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "mod2_conv1"
  top: "mod2_conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod2_relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "mod2_conv2"
  top: "mod2_conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "mod2_pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "mod2_conv2"
  top: "mod2_pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod3_conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "mod2_pool1"
  top: "mod3_conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod3_relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "mod3_conv1"
  top: "mod3_conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "mod3_conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "mod3_conv1"
  top: "mod3_conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod3_relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "mod3_conv2"
  top: "mod3_conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "mod3_pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "mod3_conv2"
  top: "mod3_pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod4_conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "mod3_pool1"
  top: "mod4_conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod4_relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "mod4_conv1"
  top: "mod4_conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "mod4_conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "mod4_conv1"
  top: "mod4_conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod4_relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "mod4_conv2"
  top: "mod4_conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "mod4_pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "mod4_conv2"
  top: "mod4_pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod5_conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "mod4_pool1"
  top: "mod5_conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod5_relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "mod5_conv1"
  top: "mod5_conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "mod5_conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "mod5_conv1"
  top: "mod5_conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod5_relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "mod5_conv2"
  top: "mod5_conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "mod5_pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "mod5_conv2"
  top: "mod5_pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod6_fc1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "mod5_pool1"
  top: "mod6_fc1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 4096
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 1
    stride: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod6_relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "mod6_fc1"
  top: "mod6_fc1"
}
layer {
  name: "mod6_drop1"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "mod6_fc1"
  top: "mod6_fc1"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod6_score1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "mod6_fc1"
  top: "mod6_score1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 2
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod6_upscore1"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "mod6_score1"
  top: "mod6_upscore1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 2
    bias_term: false
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod6_score2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "mod4_pool1"
  top: "mod6_score2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 2
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "crop"
  type: "Crop"
  bottom: "mod6_score2"
  bottom: "mod6_upscore1"
  top: "mod6_score2c"
}
layer {
  name: "mod6_fuse1"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "mod6_upscore1"
  bottom: "mod6_score2c"
  top: "mod6_fuse1"
  eltwise_param {
    operation: SUM
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod6_upfuse1"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "mod6_fuse1"
  top: "mod6_upfuse1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 2
    bias_term: false
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod6_score3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "mod3_pool1"
  top: "mod6_score3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 2
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "crop"
  type: "Crop"
  bottom: "mod6_score3"
  bottom: "mod6_upfuse1"
  top: "mod6_score3c"
}
layer {
  name: "mod6_fuse2"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "mod6_upfuse1"
  bottom: "mod6_score3c"
  top: "mod6_fuse2"
  eltwise_param {
    operation: SUM
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mod6_upfuse2"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "mod6_fuse2"
  top: "mod6_upfuse2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 2
    bias_term: false
    kernel_size: 8
    stride: 8
  }
}
layer {
  name: "crop"
  type: "Crop"
  bottom: "mod6_upfuse2"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "score"
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "score"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
  loss_param {
    normalize: false
  }
}
```

This is my solver.prototxt:

```
net: "models/face-detect/train_val.prototxt"
test_iter: 736
# make test net, but don't invoke it from the solver itself
test_interval: 999999999
display: 20
average_loss: 20
lr_policy: "fixed"
# lr for unnormalized softmax
base_lr: 1e-14
# high momentum
momentum: 0.99
# no gradient accumulation
iter_size: 1
max_iter: 100000
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 4000
snapshot_prefix: "models/face-detect/snapshot/train"
test_initialization: false
# Uncomment the following to default to CPU mode solving
solver_mode: CPU
```

Here is how I prepared my LMDB:

```
def load_image(img_path, size=None):
  # Load image as np.uint8 {0, ..., 255}
  # image shape: [height, width, channel]
  img = cv2.imread(img_path)
  # Resize to stack size
  if size != None:
    img = imresize(img, size);
  # Switch to BGR from RGB
  img = img[:, :, ::-1];
  # Switch to [channel, height, width]
  img = np.transpose(img, (2, 0, 1));
return img;

def load_label(img_path, size=None):
  img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
  if size != None:
    img = imresize(img, size);
  # Verbose storage to single channel
  img = np.reshape(img, [1, img.shape[0], img.shape[1]]);
return img;

def imgs_to_lmdb(img_paths, lmdb_path, dtype='rgb', size=None):
  in_db = lmdb.open(lmdb_path, map_size=int(1e12))
  with in_db.begin(write=True) as in_txn:
    for img_idx, img_path in enumerate(img_paths):
      if dtype == 'rgb':
        img = load_image(img_path, size);
      elif dtype == 'label':
        img = load_label(img_path, size);
      # Store as byte data
      img_dat = caffe.io.array_to_datum(img);
      in_txn.put('{:0>10d}'.format(img_idx), img_dat.SerializeToString());
  in_db.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `base_lr` seems to be too small. So your weights won't get updated quick enough. You should start with a `base_lr` of `1e-10`. The learning rate is multiplied with the loss gradient and used to update the weights. If the learning rate is too small the update will be very small and the convergence will be too slow. Too large a learning rate will give you erratic results. There is no magic number to start with so you have to find the right hyper-parameters for your data and network empirically.

Comment: "There is no magic number to start with" - then how about instead of saying "start with a `base_lr` of `1e-10`" just say "increase your `base_lr` until you see progress"?

Comment: @PrzemekD Experience.

Comment: @HarshWardhan Thanks for the quick reply, I've tried to decrease the base learning rate to 1e-10, 1e-8, and currently 1e-5 and I see no in the loss after 100 iterations for each. I read that the way the examples are prepared may also factor in. I've updated the post with the way I create the LMDBs, perhaps there's some clue you might find there? The images are in RGB and the labels are in 0 and 1s.

Answer (score -1):

You should also try learning rate decay. My favorite is the constant learning rate decay used in GoogleLeNet in which we reduce the learning rate by 4% every 8 epochs. A decaying learning rate helps in convergence as it tries to retain more information by reducing update capacity. This means that your network will not forget what it has already learned.

After this always use a momentum based optimizer like Adam or RMSprop. They greatly reduce the jitters in learning and ensure a smooth progressing to the minima.

Comment: Dude, the numbers that you're quoting are for classification task. @lainak is doing FCN.

Comment: The papers he has referenced reported that they used the following learning rates. **We set fixed
learning rates of 10e−3
, 10e−4
, and 5e
−5
for FCN-AlexNet,
FCN-VGG16, and FCN-GoogLeNet, respectively, chosen by
line search**

Comment: Read the contents of voc-fcn8s, voc-fcn16s and voc-fcn32s in the github link that he's shared. See the solver.prototxt files. I have done this training so many times.